# pandas merge from mysql datatype mismatch issue

Tags: mysql, pandas

Consider the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.io.sql.read_frame("select c1,c2,c3 from table1;",mysqldb1)
df2 = pd.io.sql.read_frame("select c1,c4 from table1;",mysqldb2)
df =  pd.merge(df1,df2,on='c1',how='inner')
```

This works most of the time.  I believe I am having a problem because in mysqldb1 c1 is a varchar whereas in mysqldb2 c1 is an INTEGER.  I can't change this state of affairs.  But now, because

```
df1.c1.dtype != df2.c1.dtype
```

pd.merge returns an empty dataframe.

I have tried casting, i.e.

```
df2['c1'] = df2.c1.astype(object)
```

and then tried the merge, to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried converting df1.c1 to int ? Or some of them can't be converted to int ?

Comment: I have.  As you suggested, some of them can't be converted to int

Comment: I have seen varchars from SQL have trailing spaces. Maybe you can check that.

Comment: I have seen that as well, but I have check that this is not the issue here

Comment: Instead of object you should try to cast as string. I've had success with this in the past regarding SQL pulls from varchar

Comment: @cwharland, you should write that up as the fix, because it worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in cases of SQL reads to a dataframe the varchar columns are read as raw strings but pandas lists all string columns as "object."

The quick fix in this situation is to convert the `c1` column to string.

```
df['c1'] = df.c1.astype(string)
```

This will cast all of your int `c1` values to string.

A deeper fix, if you think all `c2` values should be cast to integers, would be to write a function that goes row by row casting as `int` and explicitly deals with `c2` values that have difficulties casting.  But it's not entirely needed.